# Set image from android.R.drawable in image view android

Tags: android, imageview

i know how to set image/icon from our res/drawable

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageSearch" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/android_green_3d"/>
```

If we set it directly from the code:
imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_green_3d);

But we can also get the icon from android.R.drawable like this:
imageView1.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_more);

How to set image/icon in xml id the source is android.R.drawable? Anyone know?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Thats easy: change `@drawable/` to `@android:drawable/`. Code completion didn't work in this case, so you should search in the GIT repository or online for the images and their names