# How I can use my assets already exported from skech in my Android studio project

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio, sketch-3

I've started developing my first **Android application**. I've designed the UI elements in **sketch** and after I've exported the assets to my project in *Android Studio*, I don't know how to use it, like how am I going to use the png-assets in the layouts?

Thank you.

Comment: in image view provide src drawable the name of image like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683179/set-image-from-android-r-drawable-in-image-view-android

Comment: That's a bit vague for a Stack Overflow question. You should provide more details or research a bit more by yourself